# Did I forfeit 'Foxiest of the Hounds' if hacking a turret set an alarm off?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm on my first non-Pacifist stealth play trying for the [Foxiest of the Hounds](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Foxiest_of_the_Hounds) achievement.

I'm inside the legendary FEMA encampment and I made to that one room where there are like 5 guards in a row in front of a turret.

I let Zeke live, so I know the login/password to the security terminal is "spaxxor"/"neuralhub", so I can set the turrent to friendly and just murder them, but this seems to set off an alarm. It wasn't my fault the turret set the alarm off, but I am assuming that this disqualifies me. I can't even tell if I lost the [Smooth Operator](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Smooth_Operator) bonus until I get to the boss.

Am I right? Did I lose my shot at the achievement?

Answer (score 3):

Getting this achievement has nothing to do with "alarming" enemies. It is to be taken literally - there should be no alarms set off at all to get this achievement. You mention that you set off an alarm because of the turret - which means you will not get this achievement. Can you disable all alarms before using the turret?

See the discussion [here](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=120094) and [here](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=121040).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we will have to ensure that all alarms in the area are turned off before hacking the turret or else you will not be able to get Foxiest of the Hounds. But I believe it doesn't necessarily cancel Smooth Operator.